# Is this verse from Narada Pancharatra: Rā śabdoṁ uccāraṇā bhaktoṁ bhakti mukti karātisā, dhā śabdoṁ uccāraṇe naiva dhāvata seva hare padam

Tags: puranas, mantras, reference-request, shloka, radha

I am trying to identify if this shloka Narada Pancharatra:

> Rā śabdoṁ uccāraṇā bhaktoṁ bhakti mukti karātisā, dhā śabdoṁ uccāraṇe naiva dhāvata seva hare padam

रा शब्दों उच्चारणा भक्तों भक्ति मुक्ति करातिसा, धा शब्दों उच्चारणे नैव धावत सेव हरे पदम

```
रा (Rā): The syllable "Rā" signifies, and its pronunciation grants
शब्दों (śabdoṁ): Words
उच्चारणा (uccharaṇā): Pronunciation
भक्तों (bhaktoṁ): Devotees
भक्ति (bhakti): Devotion
मुक्ति (mukti): Liberation
करातिसा (karātisā): Bestows, grants
धा (dhā): The syllable "Dhā" signifies
शब्दों (śabdoṁ): Words
उच्चारणे (uccharaṇe): In pronunciation
नैव (naiva): Only
धावत (dhāvata): Runs
सेव (seva): Service
हरे (hare): To the Supreme Personality of Godhead
पदम (padam): Abode, state
```

It means after uttering the word

1. **Ra** you get moksha
2. **Dha** you get service of Shri Hari

any help is appreciated.